# RethinkDB: time travel (i.e. keep old as well)

Tags: rethinkdb

I am thinking about using RethinkDB for an app and need to implement historic versioning. In PostgreSQL I implemented Time Travel, where each update or delete triggered a function where the NEW was inserted as new by +1 to the version number and assigning the `valid_from = now()`, whilst the old was made historic by changing the `valid_to` field.

Can I do the same thing in RethinkDB?

I have set up a new database, table and followed the instructions but everything seems to want to do upserts.

Answer (score 0):

I answered another question [similar to this one over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781967/1076057).

Basically, you can do this really easily by just setting certain expectations in your data model. I'm also going to assume that a document is updated only a finite amount of times. At the moment there's a recommended 16MB limit on documents in RethinkDB, so if you expect the data to go beyond that, then you should instead insert a new document and do the valid property boolean flipping as you mentioned.

Basically, rather than create a whole new row|document when one is updated, you have an property whose value is an array in the document itself:

```
{
   id: "a randomly generated uuid",
   order_id: 1,
   orders: [
      {
         quantity: 40, price: 100, timestamp: "12:35AM 4/22/2016" // Newest modification
      },
      {
         quantity: 20, price: 100, timestamp: "12:03AM 4/22/2016" // Original order
      }
   ]
}
```

Every time you modify the document, you just modify the index 0 of the array and then insert the newest version of the document at the beginning. So we if we modified this example sale document above, it would now look like this:

```
{
   id: "a randomly generated uuid",
   order_id: 1,
   orders: [
      {
         quantity: 80, price: 100, timestamp: "1:00AM 4/22/2016" // Newest modification
      },
      {
         quantity: 40, price: 100, timestamp: "12:35AM 4/22/2016" // Newest modification
      },
      {
         quantity: 20, price: 100, timestamp: "12:03AM 4/22/2016" // Original order
      }
   ]
}
```

Does this make sense? You can find some example Javascript code in the other answer I linked.